# VSCode built-in extension "typescript-language-features" has started a tsserver, is there's a way to interaction with it by my extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am developing a extension that needs some ability base on tsserver, as I know VSCode built-in extension "typescript-language-features" has started a tsserver, is there's a way to interaction with it by my extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. You can interact with it indirectly though VS Code apis but you cannot run commands against the TS Server directly and your extension cannot get access to its AST or type information